# MinMaxScaler caused much worse result (R2 is lower) in linear regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, scaling

I was trying to apply linear regression for an automobile dataset where some of variables are categorical and the target is the price. I wanted to scale the variables, but using scaler makes the result(RMSE and R2 score) much worse.

This is my code:

```
y_target = data['price']
X_data = data.drop(['price'], axis=1)
X_dummies = pd.get_dummies(X_data, dtype=int)
```

If I use any scaler, and perform linear regression, it yields RMSE greater than 1e15 and R2 score less than -1e20 as a result:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from time import time

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X_dummies, y_target, test_size=0.3, random_state=int(time()))
X_scaler = MinMaxScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = X_scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = X_scaler.transform(X_test)

lr_model = LinearRegression()
lr_model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
y_pred = lr_model.predict(X_test_scaled)
print("RMSE:", np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))
print("R2 Score:", lr_model.score(X_test_scaled, y_test))
```

And if I just implement Linear Regression without scaling, RMSE is about 2700 and R2 score is about 0.9. Why this happens?

Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/toramky/automobile-dataset

Comment: you are scaling the dummy coded categorical data which could be causing the problem

Comment: @CemKoçak The values of categorical data are 0 or 1 so I thought it wasn't scaled by MinMaxScaler...

Comment: thats what I think too, but when I saw your question I vaguely remembered that I learned from somewhere that it could have introduce problems, so I googled it and found decent amount of people claiming the same, still unsure if that could be the case I decided to comment that instead of an aswer. Anyway did it help by any chance? Otherwise when I have freetime I will take a look at it